# Reduce scroll speed when using drag-and-drop from itemtouchhelper.callback on Android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a problem with my recycler view and the ItemTouchHelper. Callback class. When I want to drag-and-drop an item in my recycler view from the bottom to the top. The scrolling goes up almost until the beginning and I don't know why?

This is an example :

[Example.gif](https://ibb.co/SwnL2FY)

Comment: Hi, i have similar issue. Did you find the solution?

Comment: Yes I found the solution.  I had add some sort of padding to my reclyclerview and by removing it the scroll speed went back to normal.